# can i install the broadcom sta wireless driver to kubuntu from windows?

Tags: wireless, drivers, software-installation, kubuntu, broadcom

I need to install this driver for my wireless internet. I have windows and i was wondering if i downloaded the drive to windows could I transfer it to kubuntu and install it there? I understand installing on linux can be troublesome at times for newer users so how would I go about that?

Comment: What wireless card and which driver? You can sometimes use windows drivers , but usually not

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download it on Windows and put it on a flash drive and put it on Kubuntu,

but you might want to just connect the Xubuntu machine to Ethernet and install it like that. Much simpler.